# Easy Regex question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to replace the first 12 digits of credit card numbers with X's in a predictable blob of text that contains the string:

Credit Card Number: 1234123412341234

Here's my PHP function:

```
preg_replace('/Credit Card Number: ([0-9]{12})/','Credit Card Number: XXXXXXXXXXXX',$str);
```

Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb question: you are assigning the returned value back to `$str` right?

```
$str = preg_replace('/(Credit Card Number: [0-9]{12}/','Credit Card Number: XXXXXXXXXXXX',$str);
```

Comment: Actually KennyTM asked the same question first. +1. Guess I was lucky :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see what's wrong. Perhaps you forgot to assign the result?

```
$str = preg_replace('/Credit Card Number: [0-9]{12}/','Credit Card Number: XXXXXXXXXXXX',$str);
```

Also, the capturing around `([0-9]{12})` is unnecessary if you don't need it.

Comment: The reason I put that there is because it was looking for "Credit Card Number: 1" 16 times in a row, rather than just the digit 16 times in row. It was matching the whole pattern 16 times, in other words.

The problem right now is that there's no match. :(

Comment: @Aaron: Then you have some misplaced parenthesis. The `{12}` only applies on the pattern before it, i.e. `[0-9]`, not the whole pattern, unless you write `/(Credit Card Number: [0-9]){12}/`.